# How to intercept router before page load in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm currently using a custom app `_app.ts` in my Next project.

```
// import App from 'next/app'

import { useEffect } from "react"
import Router from 'next/router'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
    useEffect(() => {
        const handleRouteChange = url => {
          console.log('App is changing to: ', url)
        }

        Router.events.on('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
        return () => {
          Router.events.off('routeChangeStart', handleRouteChange)
        }
    }, [])


    return <Component {...pageProps} />
  }

  // Only uncomment this method if you have blocking data requirements for
  // every single page in your application. This disables the ability to
  // perform automatic static optimization, causing every page in your app to
  // be server-side rendered.
  //
  // MyApp.getInitialProps = async (appContext) => {
  //   // calls page's `getInitialProps` and fills `appProps.pageProps`
  //   const appProps = await App.getInitialProps(appContext);
  //
  //   return { ...appProps }
  // }

  export default MyApp
```

It seems that if i do a hard reload so if enter `localhost:3000/` in the browser, the event never fires. If I enter `localhost:3000/test` it also never fires.

It seems that it will only fire on `Route.push` calls or `<link>` calls

Is there anyway to "intercept" the routes so that I can to redirect users on certain conditions on certain routes if they enter the route on the browser?

Comment: Have you tried using [Router.beforePopState](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerbeforepopstate)?

Answer (score 3):

`next/router` is a client-side router. When you reload a page or enter the address in a browser, the request is handled by the server, so you wouldn't see events like `routeChangeStart`.

You can implement client-side redirecting that would work with both client-side and server-side routing.

Client-side redirect:

```
const router = useRouter();

useEffect(() => {
  router.push('/redirectLocation');
}, [])
```

If you need to make redirect on a server side before it responds to a browser, you would have to implement a custom server.

[Custom Server](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-server)